# Convert string to integer in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How gnuplot convert a string to integer

I wonder if there is an easy way to convert a string to integer.
For example, I want a way as like strtointeger("2") to return an integer 2.

columns="2 3"

plot for [i in columns] "mydata.dat" using 1:strtointeger(i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `i` in `[i in columns]` is actually a string. So, convert it to an integer via `int(i)`.

If you want to plot a column defined by an integer variable, use `... using (column(i))...`.

So, in combination:

**Code:**

```
### plot column numbers from a sequence in a string
reset session
set key top left

$Data <<EOD
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
51 52 53 54 55
EOD

columns="2 3 5 1 4"

plot for [i in columns] $Data using 1:(column(int(i))) w lp title sprintf("Column %s",i)
### end of code
```

In your case remove the datablock `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` and in the plot command replace `$Data` with `"mydata.dat"`

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @theozh. And why is this a wrong way by using int(i) directly--`using 1:(int(i))` rather than `using (column(int(i)))`. I mean the function `column` must be used with parentheses, but parentheses used with `int` is a wrong use, why?

Comment: if you take `(int(i))` it will be a constant with value `i`. Whereas `(column(i))` are the values from the `i`th column.

Comment: According to the manuel of gnuplot, the argument of the function int is a `real` type. Really thanks to your answer, which let me know that `string` type can also be used with `int`!

Comment: apparently, gnuplot tries to make a number out of the argument. 
`int(1.23)`, `int("1.23")` and even `int("1.23abc")` will work, 
whereas `int(abc1.23)` or `int("abc1.23")` will give error messages.

Comment: just for completeness: actually, `using 1:int(i)` would also give the same desired result like `using (column(int(i)))`, in contrast to `using 1:(int(i))`, (note the additional parentheses).